# Apache Directory Studio--Default LDAP Server (on Windows) Not Listed

Tags: apache

I am setting up ApacheDS and using the Apache Directory Studio tool to do so. I have installed ApacheDS on a Windows 8 platform, which by default installs as a Windows service with Automatic start-up.

When I open Studio, the running instance of ApacheDS does not appear in the "LDAP Server" panel (I have verified the Windows service is running), yet I am able to create a Connection to the default server (after which the server still does not appear in the LDAP Server panel).

Since the appearance of the instance of the LDAP Server is necessary for accessing/managing the configuration options in Studio, is there any way configure Studio to "find" the Default/running instance? Or must I always define a new instance, and ignore the default installation instance (setting the Windows service start-up to manual)?